# Register a file specified by open

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

So I have this small bundle with applescript made, and it even seems to work as it should. However, it appearently doesnt open my files when it is asked to via the `open` utility. It works though when I use the finder. Can anybody help me? My code is this:

```
on open theFile
    set runner to ((path to me)'s POSIX path) & "Contents/MacOS/desk_parse"
    -- We need to escape some stuff here.
    -- Expected output: '/path/to/bundle.app//Contents/MacOS/dsk_parse' '/path/to/app.desk'
    do shell script "'" & runner & "' '" & (POSIX path of theFile) & "' &"
    --display dialog runner
end open
```

Again, it works from finder, but not from command line like:

```
open "theFile.ext"
```

My Info.plist rads and also accepts the extension I saved into it. So that association actualy works.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior: the `open` handler applies to:

- Files dropped on the application from Finder
- Files opened with for example `tell app "Finder" open ... using path to "Your Application"`

But not to:

- Files passed as arguments to `open -a`
- Files opened in the application if the application is made the default application for a file type

You might create the application with Automator or [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) instead.

With Automator, use a Run AppleScript action like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    say (POSIX path of item 1 of input)
end run
```

With Platypus, check "Accept dropped items" and use a normal run handler:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv
    say item 1 of argv
end
```